# Is it possible to create a new User Group subsite level only

Tags: permissions, site-collection, user

Whenever I create a new user group in a subsite, the same user group is getting added at the top level site as well. Is it possible to create a new User Group on the subsite level only, either programmatically or not?

Answer (score 2):

No. Permission groups live in Site Collections (Sites), not sites (Webs).

Answer (score 1):

If you try to add a group using `SPWeb.Groups.Add()`, you will get below error

"You cannot add a group directly to the Groups collection. You can add a group to the SiteGroups collection."

Solution
To resolve above error follow below steps

1) Add group to site collection level by using

```
Sitecollection.SiteGroups.Add(GroupName, Web.SiteAdministrators[0], null, "Default Group for WorkShop Site");
```

2) Now again get the group

```
SPGroup secGroup = Sitecollection.SiteGroups[GroupName];
```

3) Populate a Role Assignment as shown below

SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(secGroup);

4) Define a Role Definition

```
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = Sitecollection.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
```

5) Add role Definition to

```
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
```

6) Break the Inheritance

```
Web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
```

7) Get the list of Role Assignments to list item and remove one by one

```
SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = Web.RoleAssignments;
                      for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count – 1; i >= 0; i–)
                      {
                          SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                      }
```

8)finally add the group

```
   Web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
```

Complete Code:

```
using (SPSite Site = new SPSite("Your site url"))
           {
               using (SPWeb Web = Site.OpenWeb())
               {
                   using (SPWeb Sitecollection = Site.OpenWeb())
                   {
                       var GroupName = "Your group name";
                       Sitecollection.SiteGroups.Add(GroupName, Web.SiteAdministrators[0], null, " Default Group for WorkShop Site");
                       SPGroup secGroup = Sitecollection.SiteGroups[GroupName];
                       SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(secGroup);
                       SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = Sitecollection.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
                       roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);
                       Web.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                       //Get the list of Role Assignments to list item and remove one by one.
                       SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = Web.RoleAssignments;
                       for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count – 1; i >= 0; i–)
                       {
                           SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i);
                       }
                       Web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                   }
                   returnCondition = true;
               }
           }
```

[Link to source](http://pathikhrawal.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/sharepoint-2010-adding-group-to-sub-site-programmatically/)

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible we can create new groups at sub site level only,

Following is the link where they have created sites as well as groups programatically,

http://sharepointlive.blogspot.in/2009/06/how-to-create-create-new-sharepoint.html